# Javascript fileReader

Tags: javascript, filereader

I've been working on a page that aa user will be able to load some local files and basically stream them to the browser, I'm having problems with the below code in IE10, it runs through fine in IE10, firefox and chrome.

If I put it though an interval IE10 won't read it after the source file changes :(
however firefox and chrome can, anyone know of a workaround (besides don't use IE10)?

```
setInterval(updateLog, 5000);
function updateLog(){
for (j=0;j<LogList.length;j++){
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e){
    document.getElementById("LogList").innerHTML += e.target.result;
  }
  reader.readAsText(LogList[j].file);
}}
```

Thankyou for any help

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
setInterval(updateLog, 5000);
function updateLog(){
 for (j=0;j<LogList.length;j++){
      var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e){
    document.getElementById("LogList").innerHTML += "<pre>"+e.target.result+"</pre>";
   }
 reader.readAsText(LogList[j].file);
}}
```

and follow the link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ie/ms533897.aspx